# What is wrong with my 2 bit adder?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, adder

I'm trying to make a 2 bit adder in Logism.  I made a half adder and a full adder chained together. Some equations work, and some don't. I'm using the structure that I see everywhere on how to make an adder. I don't know what's happening.

[image: My schematic in Logism]

Comment: Show what is not working.

Comment: If you designed this you should know how it is **supposed** to work. The simulator will let you look at every internal signal, so just follow the signals from input to output. When you find the incorrect value you know you have found the incorrect logic.

Comment: Well, the problem is when you do an equation such as 0 + 1, it outputs 010, since the sum of the full adder is connected to the LED. This is what I've seen in schematics, so I'm probably doing something wrong, and I don't know what.

Comment: Write down the function on each signal - as you expect it, and see if it behaves per the expectation. So it either doesn't, or your expectation is not correct.

Comment: @jort57 Your inputs are [A1,A0]=[SW3,SW1] and [B1,B0]=[SW4,SW2] from what I see there. You are correctly feeding A0 and B0 to one half-adder, feeding A1 and B1 to another half-adder, with the least significant bit of the result from the sum of A0 and B0 (also correct), the next most significant bit of the result from the sum-out of your third half-adder, which accepts the sum out of A1+B1 and the carry-out of A0+B0, also correct. And finally your highest order bit of the result is an OR of the carry out of two correctly selected half-adders. Looks okay!

Comment: @jonk Thank you!! That works. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct. :)

Comment: @jort57 I added something. Hope that is what you were looking to see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you were confused about the switches you set up. I'm not sure. But I think you actually got everything right. Here's a re-drawing that mirrors your own example:

[image]

I've also added a test process to validate the results, as you can see on the right side there.

So I believe you did everything correctly, except that you got mixed up on which switch belonged to which bit on the input side.